# Does Dim x as Decimal = 100.0m do a cast from double to decimal implicitly?

Tags: vb.net

If I have the code:

```
Dim x as Decimal = 100.0m
```

Is it casting from a double to a decimal implicitly.  How would I do this explicitly in vb.net?

Comment: [Decimal Explicit Conversion (Double to Decimal)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9sc2bx9h.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want:

```
Dim x as Decimal = 100.0d
```

The decimal literal in C# is `m`, but is `d` in vb.net. This produces no casting whatsoever. To cast a double to a decimal (`r` is the double literal in vb.net) you could say:

```
Dim x as Decimal = CType(100r, Decimal)
Dim x as Decimal = CType(100.0, Decimal)
```

Answer (score 3):

The literal suffix for decimal is "m|M" in C#.  In VB.NET, the literal suffix for decimal is "d|D".  If I understand your question, the statement should read:

Dim x as Decimal = 100.0d

The VB.NET compiler will interpret the numeric literal as a decimal at compile time so no casting is required.